# Youtube API v.3 - PHP - Refresh Token revoked unexpectly

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

we have developed an offline service with **Youtube API v.3** and **PHP**.

We have correctly obtained an access token and a refresh token from Google OAuth and our app works flawlessly; the app uses the access token and, when that token is outdated, it requires a new access token thru refresh token.

But, after a period of time (larger than an hour), it seems that the refresh token is revoked. What we see is that our app requests a new access token thru refresh token we gained earlier but it obtains an invalid access token (youtube refuses the authentication) and the app stops working.

When we check the youtube account associated to the failed refresh token, we found that our app is not authorized anymore (it is not listed on the authorized app).

Is there a policy from Google that revokes third party application? Or are we missing something on the Oauth flow?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the expected behavior. Can you keep an eye on this and see what happens - e.g. how long does it take for the token to get revoked? Is it possible it was inadvertently revoked during a testing stage?

Comment: Hello, 
I will surely keep an eye on this.
Now, for me, it is difficult to provide the time when the token has been revoked, because we provide this service for third parties that autonomously authorize our app thru OAuth. 
Nevertheless I setup an internal account to track when and what happens.
Just to say, even if it is possible that our customers revoke the app access, I don't think they do that because they barely know where to search Security Panel on Google Account. Is it possible that Google prompt for disable Oauth to user like the new 2 step authentication, on account login?